# Access GCP Managed Prometheus metrics from Grafana on Windows

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, prometheus, grafana

I have installed Grafana (running at localhost:3000) and Prometheus (running at localhost:9090) on Windows 10, and am able to add the latter as a valid data source to the former. However, I want to create Grafana dashboards for data from Google's Managed Prometheus service. How do I add Google's Managed Prometheus as a data source in Grafana, running on Windows 10? Is there a way to accomplish this purely with native Windows binaries, without using Linux binaries via Docker?

Answer (score 1):

I've not done this (myself yet).

I'm also using Google's (very good) Managed Service for Prometheus.

It's reasonably well-documented [Managed Prometheus: Grafana](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/query#ui-grafana)

There's an important caveat under [Authenticating Google APIs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/query#grafana-oauth): "Google Cloud APIs all require authentication using OAuth2; however, Grafana doesn't support OAuth2 authentication for Prometheus data sources. To use Grafana with Managed Service for Prometheus, you must use the [Prometheus UI](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/query#ui-prometheus) as an authentication proxy.

Step #1: use the [Prometheus UI](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/query#ui-prometheus)

The Prometheus UI is deployed to a GKE cluster and so, if you want to use it remotely, you have a couple of options:

1. Hacky: port-forward
2. Better: expose it as a service

Step #2: Hacky

```bash
NAMESPACE="..." # Where you deployed Prometheus UI

kubectl port-forward deployment/frontend \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
${PORT}:9090
```

Step #3: From the host where you're running the port-forward, you should now be able to configure Grafana to use the Prometheus UI datasource on `http://localhost:${PORT}`. `localhost` because it's port-forwarding to your (local)host and `${PORT}` because that's the port it's using.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daz. Unfortunately I don't have any access to the GKE cluster via Cloud Shell or anything. A Service Account has been set up for auth and the JSON key file  and Project ID have been provided to me. Apparently the way to do it with Docker is to configure the Compose YAML to use the _gke.gcr.io/prometheus-engine/frontend_ container image to run the Prometheus UI Frontend service, authenticating with the key file & the specified Project ID. The frontend service running in Docker has _web.listen-address=:9090_, and exposes the container port to the host with "9090:9090".

Comment: Now my question is, if the Prometheus UI Linux container running in Docker on Windows is basically functioning as a thin authentication proxy, isn't there a Windows binary for the same such that the same purpose can be achieved without Docker?

I found what looks to be the Go source for it at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/tree/main/cmd/frontend, but couldn't manage to compile it for Windows. :(

Comment: You should be able to run the container from anywhere. The Service Account key provides the identity that is used to authenticate to Google Cloud services etc. We're veering from the original question, perhaps you could ask a new question with the errors that you received compiling the UI for Windows? I don't see any obvious reason from the imports/source why it couldn't compile on Windows

Comment: My aim is to not rely on a container inside Docker at all, but to simply get the Prometheus Frontend UI to do its job as an authentication proxy from Windows itself, using Windows binaries. I appreciate your suggestion however and have asked about compilation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74602504/how-to-compile-the-prometheus-ui-static-binary-for-windows).

Answer (score -1):

Now we can connect gcp prometheus directly from grafana using service account. Feature available from version 9.1.X

I have tested gmp with standalone Grafana on GKE it is working well as expected.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/google-cloud-monitoring/google-authentication/

Comment: but that will NOT connect you to the prometheus endpoint, so you will not be able to use promql right? you would have to use MQL instead, which is google cloud monitoring query language: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/google-cloud-monitoring/query-editor/