# How to compile the Prometheus UI static binary for Windows?

Tags: windows, go, oauth-2.0, compiler-errors, prometheus

I am trying to [Access GCP Managed Prometheus metrics from Grafana on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74563137/20592222), for which I need to compile a Windows static binary for the Prometheus UI Frontend so that I can [use it as an authentication proxy for Grafana](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/query#grafana-oauth).

I have downloaded the [Go source from GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/tree/main/cmd/frontend) as well as Go for Windows v1.19.3.

Running `go run main.go` resulted in a bunch of errors similar to the following:

```
main.go:43:2: no required module provides package github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/pkg/ui; to add it:
        go get github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/pkg/ui
```

I whittled these down by running the `go get` commands as indicated. One such command resulted in a further complaint about `git` being unavailable, so I added the Windows binary for that as well to the PATH and proceeded with the process. Ultimately however I'm left with the following error:

```
D:\Go>go get github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/pkg/ui
go: github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/pkg/ui: no matching versions for query "upgrade"
```

A web search for the error hasn't been of much help. Suspecting some sort of version conflict I've tried with Go v1.18.8 as well, but that results in the same error. Since I'm simply Going about this blindly, having zero prior experience with Go, I'd really appreciate some help in this matter.

Comment: If the project isn't broken, you should be able to just `go install https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/cmd/frontend` and it will be compiled and the binary put into `$GOBIN`.

Comment: @Adrian: That resulted in `no required module provides package github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/cmd/frontend; to add it: go get github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/cmd/frontend`.

Running `go get ... /frontend` once again resulted in `go: github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/cmd/frontend: no matching versions for query "upgrade"`. Looks like I'm Going around in circles!

Comment: I had a quick look at this for you. I continue to think it should be possible to build a Windows binary. However, it's not as simple as `go run main.go` (presumably from within `./cmd/frontend`. The error of not finding `prometheus-engine/pkg/ui` suggests that you may not have cloned the entire repo. The repo uses a `Makefile` and there's some complexity in using Node.JS (react?) to provide the handlers.

Comment: An option is to post an issue on the [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/issues) and ask for help building the binaries for Windows. The Google PM responded to another issue and said that the binaries don't run on windows ([link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/issues/293#issuecomment-1198297706)) but, I suspect, this is "don't have a build script to run on Windows" rather than can't run on Windows. It may be that no-one has done this or no-one is motivated to document this, but you'll have asked.

Comment: @DazWilkin: Thanks, I'll try that route as well.